# How i can resolve the issue where a class would have to inherit from 2 base class

Tags: oop

Would like to know the best way to handle this situation. How it would be possible to avoid duplicate element.

```
class ABO -> Need method A and B
method C

class AO : O
method A
class BO : O
method B

class O
```

Thanks!

Comment: Some languages support multiple inheritance.  You might also try interfaces, or perhaps composition instead of inheritance.  There isn't enough information provided in the question to understand what would be the cleanest way to approach this.

Comment: The answer to this question would depend on lots of parameters, including "what OOP features does your language support?". Also, the answer may very well be "you will need to refactor (change) your hierarchy".

Comment: @David i think there enought information. A class can inherit from action of A and B. Probably the approach is wrong through. Using interfaces can fix my problem but i am using a language where i can't use type in them and i need a way to define generics.

Comment: @Rushino: No, there isn't enough information.  Nothing about these models describes their relationship to one another or what concepts they're modeling.  Inheritance might not be the correct approach at all in this case.  Additionally, what object-oriented features are even available depend heavily on the language being used, which isn't specified in the question.  As it stands this is entirely subjective and open to unnecessary debate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could avoid inheritance. If you only need a functionality and not an **IS-A** relationship, just use composition.

Hold 2 local members of the needed classes, and create a wrapper function that will call the member's functions.

C-like pseudo code example:

```
class ABO
{
   AO m_ao;
   BO m_bo;

public:

   MethodA ()
   {
       m_ao.MethodA();
   }

   MethodB()
   {
      m_bo.MethodB();
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example ?

Comment: @Rushino I've added a simple example.